# How do I access data from a python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a very simple threading example using Python 3.4.2.  In this example I am creating a five threads that just returns the character string "Result" and appends it to an array titled thread.  In another for loop iterated five times the threads are joined to the term x.  I am trying to print the result x, which should yield a list that looks like ['Resut','Result','Result','Result','Result'] but instead the print command only yields the title of the thread and the fact that it is closed.  Im obviously misunderstanding how to use threads in python.  If someone could provide an example of how to adequately complete this test case I would be very grateful.

```
 import threading

 def Thread_Test():
     return ("Result")

 number  = 5
 threads = []
 for i in range(number):
     Result = threading.Thread(target=Thread_Test)
     threads.append(Result)
     Result.start()

 for x in threads:
     x.join()
 print (x)
```

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=Thread_Test)` returns the instance of the thread not a result of any sorts. So you get an array of thread references which are printed as thread names.

Comment: You need to use Queue, to collect the data, Please find the concept here

https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/

Comment: Thanks Andrey, can you provide an example of how Que is implemented for such an example code.

Comment: @Jon please find the example below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please find the below simple example for queue and threads,

```
import threading
import Queue
import timeit

q = Queue.Queue()
number = 5

t1 = timeit.default_timer()
# Step1: For example, we are running multiple functions normally
result = []
def fun(x):
    result.append(x)
    return x

for i in range(number):
    fun(i)
print result ," # normal result"
print (timeit.default_timer() - t1)

t2 = timeit.default_timer()   

#Step2:  by using threads and queue

def fun_thrd(x,q):
    q.put(x)
    return
for i in range(number):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = fun_thrd, args=(i,q))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

thrd_result = []

while True:
    if not q.empty():
     thrd_result.append(q.get())
    else:
       break

print thrd_result , "# result with threads involved"
print (timeit.default_timer() - t2)

t3 = timeit.default_timer() 

#step :3 if you want thread to be run without depending on the previous thread

threads = []

def fun_thrd_independent(x,q):
    q.put(x)
    return

def thread_indep(number):
    for i in range(number):
        t = threading.Thread(target = fun_thrd_independent, args=(i,q))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

thread_indep(5)

for j in threads:
    j.join()

thread_indep_result = []

while True:
    if not q.empty():
        thread_indep_result.append(q.get())
    else:
       break

print thread_indep_result # result when threads are independent on each other   
print (timeit.default_timer() - t3)
```

## output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # normal result
3.50475311279e-05
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # result with threads involved
0.000977039337158
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  result when threads are independent on each other
0.000933170318604
```

It will hugely differ according to the scale of the data

Hope this helps,  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clear example.  One question, should t1.join() be outside of the for loop.  Shouldn't the loop start each thread execution and then join the results in another for loop, otherwise it has to wait for one thread to complete before it can start the next thread.

Comment: @Jon It can be either ways, depends on what u want.. sometimes you may want to run thread after thread.

Comment: Thank you for the added example.  My sample problem was just a simplification for a highly parallelizable numerical method that I am trying to implement using threads to accelerate the calculation time.  Your implementation looks like it actually takes longer than the normal result and when I apply it to my problem it does not speed it up at all, in fact it adds a few seconds to the calculation.  Am I misreading something in your solution?

Comment: @Jon The above example is just a sample to the concept. At the same time, threads should be used carefully, according to your requirement,  please see here for the concept. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/why-using-more-threads-makes-it-slower-than-using-less-threads

Comment: @Jon In the above example , I was showing how you can return the values using Queue, but in the same example, each thread is created for each range of number(because of the function) so the more limit, the threads are more and the burden is more. So, you should modify the threading system you are implementing according to your code.  Hope you understood.  Thanks

Comment: @Jon try to change the number (100,1000,10000) and so on for the above example , you can see the performance changes for each scenario. Threads should be mounted carefully according to the program and system.

Comment: After some reading I have found that if you are trying to accelerate the code you should not use thread, it will not accelerate the method because of the design of python.  According to a number of articles you should use multiprocess in python in order to speed the code up.

Comment: @Jon even multiprocess should be handled properly, because they are memory independent by nature, if you want to share the memory between processes, then they also should be used carefully and process performance highly depends on your system's core capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, as this is similar to concurrency in C++ which I have a decent amount of experience with.  Unfortunately the traditional threading methods in Python are handled very different at the processor level.  I have a processor that should be capable of parallelism in Python, I just need to master the syntax of the general process then I can focus on locks and mutex syntax.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between creating a thread and trying to get values out of a thread. Generally speaking, you should never try to use `return` in a thread to provide a value back to its caller. That is not how threads work. When you create a thread object, you have to figure out a different way of get any values calculated in the thread to some other part of your program. The following is a simple example showing how values might be returned using a list.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import threading


def main():
    # Define a few variables including storage for threads and values.
    threads_to_create = 5
    threads = []
    results = []
    # Create, start, and store all of the thread objects.
    for number in range(threads_to_create):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: results.append(number))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    # Ensure all threads are done and show the results.
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you absolutely insist that you must have the ability to return values from the target of a thread, it is possible to override some methods in `threading.Thread` using a child class to get the desired behavior. The following shows more advanced usage and demonstrates how multiple methods require a change in case someone desires to inherit from and override the `run` method of the new class. This code is provided for completeness and probably should not be used.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys as _sys
import threading


def main():
    # Define a few variables including storage for threads.
    threads_to_create = 5
    threads = []
    # Create, start, and store all of the thread objects.
    for number in range(threads_to_create):
        thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=lambda: number)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    # Ensure all threads are done and show the results.
    print([thread.returned for thread in threads])


class ThreadWithReturn(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
        super().__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)
        self.__value = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            if self._target:
                return self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        finally:
            del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs

    def _bootstrap_inner(self):
        try:
            self._set_ident()
            self._set_tstate_lock()
            self._started.set()
            with threading._active_limbo_lock:
                threading._active[self._ident] = self
                del threading._limbo[self]

            if threading._trace_hook:
                _sys.settrace(threading._trace_hook)
            if threading._profile_hook:
                threading. _sys.setprofile(threading._profile_hook)

            try:
                self.__value = True, self.run()
            except SystemExit:
                pass
            except:
                exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = self._exc_info()
                self.__value = False, exc_value
                if _sys and _sys.stderr is not None:
                    print("Exception in thread %s:\n%s" %
                          (self.name, threading._format_exc()), file=_sys.stderr)
                elif self._stderr is not None:
                    try:
                        print((
                            "Exception in thread " + self.name +
                            " (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):"), file=self._stderr)
                        print((
                            "Traceback (most recent call last):"), file=self._stderr)
                        while exc_tb:
                            print((
                                '  File "%s", line %s, in %s' %
                                (exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename,
                                    exc_tb.tb_lineno,
                                    exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name)), file=self._stderr)
                            exc_tb = exc_tb.tb_next
                        print(("%s: %s" % (exc_type, exc_value)), file=self._stderr)
                    finally:
                        del exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb
            finally:
                pass
        finally:
            with threading._active_limbo_lock:
                try:
                    del threading._active[threading.get_ident()]
                except:
                    pass

    @property
    def returned(self):
        if self.__value is None:
            self.join()
        if self.__value is not None:
            valid, value = self.__value
            if valid:
                return value
            raise value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```