# Pass variable from daughter thread to main program?

Tags: python, global-variables, locking, python-multithreading

Is there a way to pass the variables (a and b) from the "task" function in the daughter thread (thread1) back into the while loop of the main thread (thread0)? After being used once in thread0, the idea is to automatically reset them back to "0".

I tried setting the variables as global but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Also, can "lock" be used on the variables in this case?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
# example of running a function in another thread
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

global a
global b
# setting some initial variables (needed?)
a = 0
b = 0


# a custom function that will run commands for new thread ("thread1")
def task():
    while True:
        global a
        global b
        
        #lets reset the values to ensure they are 0
        a = 0
        b = 0


        print "This is the TASK function.\n"
        a = int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
        b  = int(a * 5.6)
        print "I received: ", a
        print "I calculated: ", b




# create & run a new thread ("thread1")
thread = Thread(target=task)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()


while True:
    print "-------------------------------"
    print "HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0)."


    print "DEGREES received from TASK function: ", a
    print "COUNTS received from TASK function: ", b
    time.sleep(1)
```

The expected output would be:

```
python ./thread2.py 
This is the TASK function.

Enter number: -------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
5     (**** note this is the number entered by the user****)
I received:  5
I calculated:  28
This is the TASK function.
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  5
COUNTS received from TASK function:  28
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
-------------------------------
Enter number:
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
8     (**** note this is the number entered by the user****)
I received:  8
I calculated:  45
This is the TASK function.
Enter number: -------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  8
COUNTS received from TASK function:  45
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
-------------------------------
HERE I'm running the MAIN thread (thread0).
DEGREES received from TASK function:  0
COUNTS received from TASK function:  0
-------------------------------
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK please see original message (I updated it with the desired output)

Comment: Try looking at [How do I access data from a python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699837/how-do-i-access-data-from-a-python-thread).